# BizTalk receive location wasn't refresh after enable using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, biztalk

I have a simple PowerShell script to enable disabled receive location, I can see the port was enabled via BizTalk Server Administrator while the script not completed.  But when the script rechecks status, after first enabling attempt, to ensure the port enabled, it still shows the port was disabled.  Here is my script.

```
$location = get-wmiobject msbts_receivelocation -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter "name='${rcvLoc}'"
[void]$Location.Enable()   
Restart-Service -Displayname "BizTalk Service BizTalk Group : ${hostname}"
Start-Sleep -s 60 #1min
[void]$Catalog.Refresh
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: "But when the script rechecks status" - I don't see that it does that.  Do you mean BizTalk Administrator?  BT Admin does not automatically refresh the views, you have to click Refresh youself.

Comment: Boatseller - I mean during the powershell script running.
I have checked the port twice to ensure it enabled.  After the first checked, I saw the port enabled via BTS administrator with hard refresh.  But the script still sees the port was disabled.

Comment: Does anyone see something that I didn't?

Comment: So, I still don't fully understand what you mean by 'checked the port twice'.  The script doesn't check it at all.

Comment: The checking the status is not listed here.